# (discord.py) 'User' object has no attribute 'roles' when trying to change member's roles

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm attempting to write a bot that gives someone a suspended role for a certain amount of time that is specified by the moderator in the command (I know the variable is called hours even though it's going to be in seconds as it stands currently. I'll be fixing that later.) Basically, it works by the moderator saying in the message '!suspend @personmention numberofhours' and it suspends the person mentioned for that amount of time. The issue I'm having is that for some reason, the bot keeps telling me that the user object found on the line where I define the offender variable does not have an attribute roles. As far as I know, every member of a discord server has an attribute roles. What am I doing wrong that is causing the following error in which it won't recognize the offender as having roles?

Here's the error feedback I'm getting:

```
line 2943, in remove_roles
new_roles = [x.id for x in member.roles]
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'roles'
```

And then here's the actual code for the script I'm writing.

```
async def suspend(ctx, mention, hours):
    offenderid = mention.replace('<','').replace('>','').replace('!','').replace('@','')
    person = ctx.message.author
    offender = await bot.get_user_info(offenderid)

    if "437778896440524800" in [role.id for role in ctx.message.author.roles] or "437778867940229121" in [role.id for role in ctx.message.author.roles] or "437778794879647755" in [role.id for role in ctx.message.author.roles]:

        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles, name="Raider")
        await bot.remove_roles(offender, role)

        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles, name="Suspended Raider")
        await bot.add_roles(offender, role)

        time.sleep(int(hours))

        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles, name="Suspended Raider")
        await bot.remove_roles(offender, role)

        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles, name="Raider")
        await bot.add_roles(offender, role)
```

Comment: The part that raises the error doesn't seem to be in the code that you presented. And you're not showing where the `User` class is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you that the object that you received is a `User` not a `Member`. `Member`s typically have a role (at least an `everyone` role) but `User`s don't.

The code you posted doesn't contain the actual example code that raises the error so I can't reproduce. But it seems that you are trying to execute some code on a `User` object rather than a `Member`.

Comment: How exactly do I go about getting the Member object rather than the User object from the id then? I couldn't find anything in the API docs about it.

Comment: Oh wait. I see now, User is just the parent of Member, correct?

Comment: It's the super class, yes.

Comment: I had to use `<guild>.me` instead of `client.user`

Answer (score 2):

Basicly, you can have this error if you try to execute an action on the discord bot. Because the bot is a `User` class, not a `Member`. So, if you don't want to get this error anymore, you can add this line:

```py
if (ctx.)message.author == bot.user: return
```