# Creating a discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Get the list of roles for the server
    roles = message.guild.roles
    
    # Get the Member object for the user
    member = message.guild.get_member(message.author.id)
    
    # Check if the member has the desired role
    role = discord.utils.get(message.author.roles, id=[REDACTED])
    # Get the "Muted" role using the list of roles for the server
    muted = discord.utils.get(roles, id=[REDACTED])
    
    if role in member.roles:
        if message.content == '/hello':
            await message.channel.send('Hello!')
        elif message.content.startswith('/mute'):
            try:
                # Get the user to mute
                user = message.mentions[0]
                member = message.guild.get_member(user.id)
                # Check if the user is already muted
                if muted not in member.roles:
                    # Add the "Muted" role to the user
                    await member.add_roles(muted)
                    await message.channel.send(f'{user.mention} has been muted')
                else:
                    await message.channel.send(f'{user.mention} is already muted')
            except Exception as e:
                await message.channel.send('An error occurred while trying to mute the user')

client.run('[REDACTED]')
```

this is my code, idk why it won't work i get this error

```
role = discord.utils.get(message.author.roles, id=[REDACTED])
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'roles'
```

i used chatgpt so yeah xD

i spent like hours trying to figure out what's wrong, i wanted a to make a bot that gives a role to a mentioned member when used the command

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50107559/51685

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the on_message event in discord.py, you could use the command api

Then your code would look like that

```
import discord

bot = discord.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.command(pass_prefix=True)
async def mute(ctx):
    required_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=[REDACTED])
    if required_role in ctx.author.roles:
        muted_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=[REDACTED])
        if muted_role in ctx.message.mentions[0].roles:
            await ctx.send("This user is already muted.")
            return
        else:
            await ctx.message.mentions[0].add_roles(muted_role)
            await ctx.message.mentions[0].send("You have been muted in the server.")
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.mentions[0].mention} has been muted.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("You do not have permission to use this command.")

bot.run('[REDACTED]')
```

Comment: i get this error using your answer
bot = discord.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=discord.Intents.all())
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot'